# Theoretical: Could a heavily modified airship enter low Earth orbit?

Tags: launch, rockets, launch-site, booster

A high-altitude airship hitched to solid rocket boosters

As the helium-filled airship reaches its ceiling, the boosters would initiate a launch sequences, thus sending the airship into orbit. [Orbital Airship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_airship) [jpaerospace](http://www.jpaerospace.com/atohandout.pdf)

Comment: The real difficulty in getting to LEO is not altitude, but speed.  E.G. an object in orbit has about 35 times the kinetic energy, as it does gravitational potential energy.

Comment: John Powell of JP Aerospace happens to be on [thespaceshow](http://www.thespaceshow.com/live.htm) today 5 p.m. EST, if you want to call in and ask Mr. Airship-to-Space himself.